# Remover relacionamento em json de retorno do package Datatables do Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, relacionamento

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código usando laravel e o package Datatables

```
$products = Product::with('enterprise')
                   ->select(['id', 'enterprise_id', 'name'])
                   ->whereIn('enterprise_id', [1, 2]);

return Datatables::of($products)
       ->editColumn('enterprise_id', function($product){
           return $product->enterprise->name;
       })
       ->make();
```

E tenho como retorno o seguinte json:

```
[
    "12",
    "Nome empresa",
    "Nome do produto",
    {
        "id": 1,
        "client_id": 1,
        "name": "Nome empresa",
        "created_at": "2016-08-25 16:38:24",
        "updated_at": "2016-08-25 16:38:24"
    }
]
```

Como remover aquele trecho do json onde aparece o relacionamento? O que gostaria de tirar é essa parte do json:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "client_id": 1,
    "name": "Nome empresa",
    "created_at": "2016-08-25 16:38:24",
    "updated_at": "2016-08-25 16:38:24"
}
```

Já tentei usar o recurso `removeColumn` sem sucesso. E também já tentei adicionar uma nova coluna `nome_empresa` e removendo a coluna `enterprise_id` mas também sem sucesso.

O resultado que esperava receber no json seria:

```
[
    "12",
    "Nome empresa",
    "Nome do produto",
]
```

Comment: O primeiro json é o retorno da função Datatables? tem como você ao invés de retornar diretamento da funcao, atribuir o resultado dela a uma variavel $retorno, converter esta varivel para array com json_decode remover o elemento [3] desse vetor e retornar $retorno? se achar válido eu redijo uma resposta com mais detalhes.

Comment: Eu consegui remover. Vou responder minha própria pergunta para quem tiver a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver este problema basta dar um `removeColumn` no nome do relacionamento.

Em meu caso no model `Product` tinha o seguinte método para fazer o relacionamento:

```
public function enterprise(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Enterprise');
}
```

Então removi a coluna da seguinte forma:

```
->removeColumn('enterprise')
```

Pronto, isso resolver o problema e agora o json veio conforme precisava.